# Allow Blocked Content - Informing the User

Tags: intuition

I'm trying to find the best experience to informing my users to enable blocked content.

The problem is, on IE, when running an html page with scripts on a local network, it blocks it by default. The intended users have very limited computer skills so they won't know about browsers and allowing blocked content. I need to find a very-easy-to-follow method of informing my users on how to allow blocked content. Another issue is that after about 5 seconds of first loading the page the allow block content message at the bottom of the screen fades away. Here are some rough ideas I have so far:

[attention icon] To use this page, please allow blocked content (hover over and image appears, but could confuse my users). If you no longer see the option to do this, please click here (reloads the page) to try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this in a slightly different fashion. Users are going to a page and would expect the content to be there on that page. It's a poor experience if they are prevented from doing so because of the system limitations (which is not the users fault.)

My suggestion would be to try briefly educate users with a either a modal window (with pictures & description) of how to view the content **before they reach the page**, or redirect them to a page with the same content as the modal.

You want to be proactive in this, and make the use feel they are taking a positive action, instead of feeling like they done something wrong.

This would allow users to understand what will happen on the next screen, they will see the content quicker, it removes the need to refresh the page, as well as allowing them to see the content.

Answer (score 0):

I go with the previous answer. Educate your users before they get to the page. I suggest that a simplish way to do this is to use a basic PHP script, which doesn't get blocked by IE. If you want the full script you'd have to go to StackOverflow, but here's a basic run-down:

1. Page is requested
2. Check for query string (`?visited=true`)
3. If it's there, the user has already seen your info page: take no action and let them enable the content. Perhaps use a `noscript` tag to remind them.
4. If it's not there, redirect them to an info page showing instructions on how to enable the content.

Using this method, you can guarantee that they will see the info before the page. You might also want to consider cookies to save the fact that they've seen it so they don't see it every single time they visit.